# Converting a basis to a quaternion python

Tags: python, quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have information in this format (what I assume to be a rotation matrix)

`xBasis:(-0.923067, -0.221423, -0.314514)`

`yBasis:(-0.380463, 0.645773, 0.661985)`

`zBasis:(-0.0565259, -0.730718, 0.680336)`

`origin:(0, 0, 0)`

and I would like to convert it to a quaternion. Could you please advise me the best way to do so in Python?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225967/converting-a-basis-to-a-quaternion-python/) by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `quaternion_from_matrix` method from `transformations.py` in tf package

```
from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_matrix

q = quaternion_from_matrix(tr_matrix)
```

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2